# Unnecessary white space created if we use other font rather than courier

Tags: fonts

My code are as follow:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%


\setmonofont[Path = ./Fonts/ ,
UprightFont= Iosevka ,]{Iosevka}

\usepackage{textcomp,xcolor,MNsymbol}
\definecolor{mylightgrey}{rgb}{0.98, 0.98, 0.98}
\definecolor{mydarkgrey}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{myterminalstyle}{%
upquote=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
commentstyle=\slshape\footnotesize,
frameround = tttt,
frame = trbl,
backgroundcolor = \color{black!16},
showspaces = false,
showtabs = false,
breaklines=true,xleftmargin=4\p@,xrightmargin=3\p@,aboveskip=13\p@,belowskip=10\p@,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
% Comments
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
morecomment=[l]{\#},
% Keywords
keywordstyle=\color{mydarkgrey}\normalfont\bfseries,
morekeywords={awk,bash, break,case,cat,cut,cd,cp, chmod, continue,do,done,echo,elif,else,%
      env,esac,eval,exit,export,expr,false,find,function,getopts, grep,%
      hash,history,if,kill,login,ls,newgrp,nice,nohup,ps,pwd,read,rm,%
      readonly,return,set,sed,shift,then,times,trap,true,%
      ulimit,umask,unset,until,wait,while,%
      alias,bg,bind,builtin,caller,compgen,compopt,%
      complete,coproc,declare,disown,dirs,enable,fc,fg,head, help,history,%
      jobs,let,local,logout,mapfile,printf,pushd,popd,readarray,select,%
      set,suspend,sort, source,times,tr, touch, typeset,ulimit,unalias,wc, xargs,%
      mkdir, git, tail, head, uniq, open,%
      commit, merge, status, log, add, clone, init, stash, apply, %
      diff, --amend, pull, push, fetch, reset,  blame, branch, checkout, reset, %
      mv, rmdir, less, for, in, man, file, gedit, -oneline, --graph, --decorate, --all, --hard%
      say, date, cal, sudo, chown, config, geom_smooth
      },%
otherkeywords={},
alsoletter={=},
escapechar = {§},
}
\lstnewenvironment{shorttermcode}{\lstset{style=myterminalstyle}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{shorttermcode}
# assuming you saved CSB in your home directory
# navigate to the sandbox in the CSB/unix directory
cd ~CSB/unix/sandbox
\end{shorttermcode}

\end{document}
```

It works without any issue, but some unnecessary vertical white space comes if the character / comes. See the output below:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why `\p@` and not `pt`? Fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing \makeatletter. Also better don't load xltxtra and xunicode.

Instead of doing the frame with listings, better use tcolorbox. Then you won't get the white space, and also not the gray edges. I deactivated your font as I don't have it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%

%\setmonofont[Path = ./Fonts/ ,
%UprightFont= Iosevka ,]{Iosevka}

\usepackage{textcomp,xcolor,MNsymbol}
\definecolor{mylightgrey}{rgb}{0.98, 0.98, 0.98}
\definecolor{mydarkgrey}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{myterminalstyle}{%
upquote=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
commentstyle=\slshape\footnotesize,
showspaces = false,
showtabs = false,
breaklines=true,xleftmargin=4\p@,xrightmargin=3\p@,aboveskip=13\p@,belowskip=10\p@,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
% Comments
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
morecomment=[l]{\#},
% Keywords
keywordstyle=\color{mydarkgrey}\normalfont\bfseries,
morekeywords={awk,bash, break,case,cat,cut,cd,cp, chmod, continue,do,done,echo,elif,else,%
      env,esac,eval,exit,export,expr,false,find,function,getopts, grep,%
      hash,history,if,kill,login,ls,newgrp,nice,nohup,ps,pwd,read,rm,%
      readonly,return,set,sed,shift,then,times,trap,true,%
      ulimit,umask,unset,until,wait,while,%
      alias,bg,bind,builtin,caller,compgen,compopt,%
      complete,coproc,declare,disown,dirs,enable,fc,fg,head, help,history,%
      jobs,let,local,logout,mapfile,printf,pushd,popd,readarray,select,%
      set,suspend,sort, source,times,tr, touch, typeset,ulimit,unalias,wc, xargs,%
      mkdir, git, tail, head, uniq, open,%
      commit, merge, status, log, add, clone, init, stash, apply, %
      diff, --amend, pull, push, fetch, reset,  blame, branch, checkout, reset, %
      mv, rmdir, less, for, in, man, file, gedit, -oneline, --graph, --decorate, --all, --hard%
      say, date, cal, sudo, chown, config, geom_smooth
      },%
otherkeywords={},
alsoletter={=},
escapechar = {§},
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{shorttermcode}{colframe=black, colback=black!16, listing options={style=myterminalstyle},listing only }
\begin{document}

\begin{shorttermcode}
# assuming you saved CSB in your home directory
# navigate to the sandbox in the CSB/unix directory
cd ~CSB/unix/sandbox
\end{shorttermcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd change `\p@` into `pt`, there's no reason to keep it.

Comment: @egreg yes, but I was too lazy, typing \makeatletter is faster ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks, it'w working fine, can you suggest how can I reduce top, bottom and side spaces inside the shaded box??

Comment: Read the documentation of tcolorbox.