# left rule affected if change courier font to other font

Tags: listings, rules

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%


\setmonofont[Path = ./Fonts/ ,
UprightFont= Iosevka ,]{Iosevka}

\usepackage{textcomp,xcolor,MNsymbol}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mypyscriptstyle}{%
upquote=true,
language=Python,
% Basic style
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
commentstyle=\tt\footnotesize, %\rmfamily
stringstyle=\ttfamily\slshape\small,%amd remove \slshape, add upquote=true
% Line numbers
%numbers=left,
%numberstyle=\footnotesize,
%numbersep=1em,
%stepnumber=3,
% Margins and box
framextopmargin=2em,
framexbottommargin=2em,
frame=l,
backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
xleftmargin=1em,
tabsize=4,
% Show spaces
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
% Comments
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
morecomment=[l]{\#},
% Keywords
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
keywords={},
sensitive=true,
string=[b]',
morestring=[b]",
escapechar={§},
alsoletter={_, .},
% Built-in
emphstyle=\color{black!15}\bfseries,
emph={assert, break, class, continue, def, del, elif, else, except, finally, for, global, help, in, lambda, not, or, pass, raise, return, try, while, with, yield, exec, Ellipsis, None, NotImplemented, ArithmeticError, AssertionError, AttributeError, EnvironmentError, EOFError, Exception, FloatingPointError, ImportError, IndentationError, IndexError, IOError, KeyboardInterrupt, KeyError, LookupError, MemoryError, NameError, NotImplementedError, OSError, OverflowError, ReferenceError, RuntimeError, StandardError, StopIteration, SyntaxError, SystemError, SystemExit, TabError, TypeError, UnboundLocalError, UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeError, UnicodeTranslateError, ValueError, WindowsError, ZeroDivisionError, Warning, UserWarning, DeprecationWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, SyntaxWarning, OverflowWarning, RuntimeWarning, FutureWarning, abs,  any, bin, bool, callable, chr, classmethod, compile, complex, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, eval, filter, float, format, frozenset, getattr, globals, hasattr, hash, hex, id, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, iter, len, list, locals, map, max, min, object, oct, open, ord, pow, property, range, repr, reversed, round, setattr, set, slice, sorted, staticmethod, str, sum, super, tuple, type, vars, zip, apply, basestring, buffer, cmp, coerce, execfile, file, intern, long, , reduce, reload, unichr, unicode, xrange, import, __import__, print, match, search, readline, rstrip, group, VERBOSE, finditer, findall,
join, upper, lower, replace, find, count, strip, split, append, copy, clear, index, pop, sort, reverse, get, items, keys, values, update, intersection, union, symmetric_difference, difference, issubset, issuperset, if, name, mode, encoding, write, writelines, close, as, seek, whos, deepcopy, start, end, dimension, shape, ndim, size, mean, std, sqrt, exp, array, zeros, ones, arange, reshape, random, loadtxt, re, who, from, imread, imshow, loc, iloc, drop, median, hist, email, esearch, efetch, parse, description, id, seq, alignments, read  }
}

\lstnewenvironment{testermcode}{\lstset{style=mypyscriptstyle}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{testermcode}
In [1]: 2 + 2 # addition of integers
Out[1]: 4
In [2]: 2 * 2 # multiplication
Out[2]: 4
In [3]: 3 / 2 # division (returns floating-point real value)
Out[3]: 1.5
In [4]: 3 // 2 # integer division
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: 2 > 3 # logical operators return a Boolean value
Out[5]: False
In [6]: 2 == 2 # equals
Out[6]: True
In [7]: 2 != 2 # is different
Out[7]: False
In [8]: "my string" # quotes define strings
Out[8]: 'my string'
\end{testermcode}

\end{document}
```

Output came as:

[image]

Same problem I got as per my previous post [Unnecessary white space created if we use other font rather than courier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437543/unnecessary-white-space-created-if-we-use-other-font-rather-than-courier?noredirect=1#comment1097961_437543)

I've tried what Ulrike suggested, but I got framed box around, but I need the left side rule only,

Please suggest...

Comment: tcolorbox has a long and good documentation which shows all sort of options -- including how to hide the frame or only show a left rule.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Default round cornered box only created if I follow your suggestion, not able to create as like as my requirement, pl suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issues, below are the updated code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%


\setmonofont[Path = ./Fonts/ ,
UprightFont= Iosevka ,]{Iosevka}

\usepackage{textcomp,xcolor,MNsymbol}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mypyscriptstyle}{%
upquote=true,
language=Python,
% Basic style
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
commentstyle=\tt\footnotesize, %\rmfamily
stringstyle=\ttfamily\slshape\small,%amd remove \slshape, add upquote=true
% Line numbers
%numbers=left,
%numberstyle=\footnotesize,
%numbersep=1em,
%stepnumber=3,
% Margins and box
%framextopmargin=2em,
%framexbottommargin=2em,
%frame=l,
%backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
%xleftmargin=1em,
%tabsize=4,
% Show spaces
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
% Comments
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
morecomment=[l]{\#},
% Keywords
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
keywords={},
sensitive=true,
string=[b]',
morestring=[b]",
escapechar={§},
alsoletter={_, .},
% Built-in
emphstyle=\color{black!15}\bfseries,
emph={assert, break, class, continue, def, del, elif, else, except, finally, for, global, help, in, lambda, not, or, pass, raise, return, try, while, with, yield, exec, Ellipsis, None, NotImplemented, ArithmeticError, AssertionError, AttributeError, EnvironmentError, EOFError, Exception, FloatingPointError, ImportError, IndentationError, IndexError, IOError, KeyboardInterrupt, KeyError, LookupError, MemoryError, NameError, NotImplementedError, OSError, OverflowError, ReferenceError, RuntimeError, StandardError, StopIteration, SyntaxError, SystemError, SystemExit, TabError, TypeError, UnboundLocalError, UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeError, UnicodeTranslateError, ValueError, WindowsError, ZeroDivisionError, Warning, UserWarning, DeprecationWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, SyntaxWarning, OverflowWarning, RuntimeWarning, FutureWarning, abs,  any, bin, bool, callable, chr, classmethod, compile, complex, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, eval, filter, float, format, frozenset, getattr, globals, hasattr, hash, hex, id, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, iter, len, list, locals, map, max, min, object, oct, open, ord, pow, property, range, repr, reversed, round, setattr, set, slice, sorted, staticmethod, str, sum, super, tuple, type, vars, zip, apply, basestring, buffer, cmp, coerce, execfile, file, intern, long, , reduce, reload, unichr, unicode, xrange, import, __import__, print, match, search, readline, rstrip, group, VERBOSE, finditer, findall,
join, upper, lower, replace, find, count, strip, split, append, copy, clear, index, pop, sort, reverse, get, items, keys, values, update, intersection, union, symmetric_difference, difference, issubset, issuperset, if, name, mode, encoding, write, writelines, close, as, seek, whos, deepcopy, start, end, dimension, shape, ndim, size, mean, std, sqrt, exp, array, zeros, ones, arange, reshape, random, loadtxt, re, who, from, imread, imshow, loc, iloc, drop, median, hist, email, esearch, efetch, parse, description, id, seq, alignments, read  }
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}


%\lstnewenvironment{testermcode}{\lstset{style=mypyscriptstyle}}{}
\newtcblisting{testermcode}{colback=black!16,left=4pt,right=4pt,arc=0pt,leftrule=2pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,listing
options={style=mypyscriptstyle,xleftmargin=4pt},listing only }


\begin{document}

\begin{testermcode}
In [1]: 2 + 2 # addition of integers
Out[1]: 4
In [2]: 2 * 2 # multiplication
Out[2]: 4
In [3]: 3 / 2 # division (returns floating-point real value)
Out[3]: 1.5
In [4]: 3 // 2 # integer division
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: 2 > 3 # logical operators return a Boolean value
Out[5]: False
In [6]: 2 == 2 # equals
Out[6]: True
In [7]: 2 != 2 # is different
Out[7]: False
In [8]: "my string" # quotes define strings
Out[8]: 'my string'
\end{testermcode}

\end{document}
```