# listing, gray background white space problem

Tags: listings

I used the following link to implement code listing:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing

It works generally fine, but whenever I write math and do power of something for example it creates a white space between the lines just like in the picture:

[image: Problem]

This only happens in math mode when I do exponentiation. 
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
The code I'm using for the background is as follows:

```
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} 
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5} 
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codeorange}{rgb}{1,0.4,0}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}   

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{     
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},        
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},     
    keywordstyle=\color{codeorange},     
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},     
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},     
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,     
    breakatwhitespace=false,              
    breaklines=true,                      
    captionpos=b,                         
    keepspaces=true,                      
    numbers=left,                         
    numbersep=5pt,                       
    showspaces=false,                     
    showstringspaces=false,     
    showtabs=false,                      
    tabsize=2 }  

\lstset{style=mystyle, language=Python}
```

And the packages I am using is listing and color.

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to combine listings with tcolorbox and let the latter handle the background.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437551/2388