# Listing not fully filling background with escape inside

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, colorbox

I made this minimal example to showcase the problem I am having:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{xmlOrange}{HTML}{cc7a00}
\definecolor{xmlGreen}{HTML}{009900}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily,
    escapeinside={\@~}{~},
    showstringspaces=true,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    morecomment=[s][\color{xmlOrange}]{"}{"},
    morecomment=[s][\color{xmlGreen}]{<!--}{-->},
}

\newcommand{\test}{{\colorbox{background}{\color{xmlOrange}{test Text}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<root>
    <header test="@~\test~">
    </header>
</root>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

What you end with is this:

[image: weird background]

I have to make this way because the "test Text" is taken from a different from a command (this can't be changed).

If I completely remove the colorbox it works as long as the text input to the listing via LaTeX code doesn't cause a new line. Once this happens the entire line becomes white which looks even worse:

[image: emtpy line]

I tried a number of packages but they all seem to just be creating a boxes within the listing which doesn't work for my case.

Update with external file:

Using

```
\newtcbinputlisting{xmlListing}{colframe=background, colback=background, listing options={language=xml,columns=fullflexible},listing only }
```

and then using the previous example xml in a file called test.xml:

```
\xmlListing{test.xml}
```

results in this:

[image: input problem]

Comment: use the tcolorbox package to create listings with background color. see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437543/2388

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am having problems using that in conjuction with an external file.
Using it like
\begin{xmlcode}
@~\input{xml/errReq.xml}
\end{xmlcode}
Makes the first line not be formatted for some reason.

Comment: tcolorbox has  lots of options to work with external files -- and a quite good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer(and the docs+other answers found via it), solution was to simply create a newcbtinputlisting via

```
\newtcbinputlisting{\xmlListing}[1]{colframe=background, colback=background, listing options={language=xml,columns=fullflexible}, breakable, listing only,listing file={#1} }
```

and then using it with

```
\xmlListing{filename}
```